# C# - crear una clase que implemente IDispose

Tags: c#, .net

favor su colaboración en lo siguiente:

Tengo una clase Clase con N atributos:

```
public class Clase
{
    private string atrib1;
    private int atrib 2;
}
```

Deseo que cuando utilice la clase pueda hacer (creo que para un mejor manejo de recursos) un:

```
using(Clase obj = new Clase())
{
    ..........
}
```

pero no funciona así de simple verdad? tengo que implementar la interface IDispose (Clase : IDispose) e implementar explicitamente el método Dispose().

Bueno ahora si viene la pregunta del millón: ¿que código debo poner en el método Dispose() para que tanto el atributo atrib1 y el atributo atrib2 sean destruidos, liberados, etc, y también sea destruido, liberado, etc el mismo objeto en cuestión???

```
public void Dispose()
{
    ???
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso, no tiene sentido que la clase implemente la interfaz `IDisposable`, porque los únicos miembros que tiene tu clase son de tipo `String` y `int`. Los miembros de estos tipos, y la instancia de tu clase misma, no requieren que los "destruyas" tu mismo como sucede en otros ambientes de programación. De hecho, en .NET no puedes hacerlo. De esto se encarga automáticamente el *Garbage Collector* de .NET Runtime. Deja que él se encargue de ello por ti.

En realidad, solo tiene sentido implementar la interfaz en uno de 2 casos. Fuera de esos 2 casos (como es el caso tuyo), no necesitas la interfaz `IDisposable` ni necesitas usar la notación `using` para crear y usar una instancia de tu clase:

1. Uno o varios de los miembros de tu clase tiene un "handle" directo a un recurso fuera del runtime .NET. (ejemplos: conexiones de network, handle a un archivo abierto en el disco duro, otros handles Win32, etc.)  En realidad, este caso es sumamente raro (y más complicado, porque entonces debes preocuparte por definir un *finalizer* también, pero no hay necesidad de ampliar ese tema aquí), ya que usualmente no necesitas manejar estos "handles" directamente en tus clases, sino que mas bien, lo haces usando clases ya existentes del Framework que manejan estas cosas de bajo nivel para ti, lo que nos lleva al segundo caso...
2. Uno o varios de los miembros de tu clase implementa a su vez la interfaz `IDisposable` (ejemplos: `SqlConnection`, `Stream`, etc.). En ese caso, el método `Dispose()` debería ejecutar los `.Dispose()` respectivos de los miembros que implementan `IDispose`.

   Ejemplo:

   ```
   public class Clase : IDisposable
   {
       private string atrib1;
       private int atrib 2;
       private Stream stream; // Stream implementa IDisposable

       private bool disposed;

       public void Dispose()
       {
           // para evitar hacer el dispose 2 veces por nada.
           if (disposed) return;

           disposed = true;

           // Aquí llamas el ".Dispose" de todos los miembros que
           // implementan IDisposable, en este caso, solo "stream".
           // Nota que uso el operador ?. para manejar el caso cuando
           // "stream == null".
           stream?.Dispose();
       }
   }
   ```

   De paso, cabe mencionar que este ejemplo usa una versión simplificada de implementar `IDisposable` comparado a lo que se sugiere en la [documentación oficial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx). En lo personal, yo considero que este patrón simplificado es perfectamente aceptable para el 99% de los casos donde sí necesitas implementar la interfaz.  En realidad, solo necesitas el patrón sugerido por Microsoft si 1) te topas con el primer caso arriba (sumamente raro), o 2) si tu clase hereda de otra clase, y los varios niveles de herencia necesitan cooperar juntos para ejecutar el `Dispose()`.

Comment: Pffff tu respuesta fue muy muy muy clara muchas gracias, favor tengo dos consultas:
    1. que pasa si se hace Dispose mas de una vez?
    2. que pasa si se hace Dsipose sobre un objeto null?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: 1) La documentación para [IDisposable.Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx) (aunque le falta traducción) menciona que después de la primera llamada, las siguientes llamadas no deberían hacer nada. O sea que para respetar el contrato del Dispose(), debes hacerlo como en mi ejemplo donde ignoro todas las llamadas salvo la primera.  2) Si haces `obj.Dispose()` y `obj` es `null`, entonces sucederá lo mismo que cualquier otro método invocado en un objeto `null`: `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// IDisposable requiere que implementes esta función en tu clase.
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    // La siguiente línea se utiliza si el finalizador está sobreescrito (override) en otro pedazo del código.
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Puedes encontrar ejemplos aquí: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx